# Passing a variable of a class as parameter previously defined as null

Tags: c#, oop, pointers, parameters, instance

I have never realized a problem like this before. If I pass a variable which it's of a specific type but not yet instantiated it shouldn't be considered as a pointer still? In this example why I am getting null when I come back to the scope of the click event if the method GetEmployee creates a new instance.

I know that to make it work I can define the argument as a ref or out, but Employee is a class which initially was defined as null, but then I allocate a space in memory when I do new and it shouldn't be linked to the variable? Why do I lose the value later?

The scenario would be completely different if I pass already an object which all its modified properties in the inner method will remain when I come back to the scope of the click event.

This won't work

```
    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee employee = null;
        bool created = GetEmployee(employee);
    }
```

This will work

```
    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        bool created = GetEmployee(employee);
    }
```

The rest

```
    private bool GetEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee == null)
        {
            employee = new Employee();

        }
        employee.ID = 1;
        employee.Name = "John";
        return true;
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Complicating the things a little bit. This will also fail because the object has never been set to something different to null

```
    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 1;
        Employee employee = this.LoadFromDatabase(id);
        bool created = GetEmployee(employee);
    }

    private Employee LoadFromDatabase(id)
    {
        //In the inner service method if it is not found it will return null
        return Service.Instance.LoadFromDatabase(id);
    }

    private bool GetEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee == null)
        {
            employee = new Employee();

        }
        employee.ID = 1;
        employee.Name = "John";
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

While the members of employee can be modified by the caller, the reference to the employee itself can not. When passing in a reference type argument in C#, you may modify the members of that object and see the changes in the caller. However, the reference itself is passed by value and assigning to the parameter will not do anything. To do what you're trying to do, simply return the employee rather than erroneously trying to modify the reference:

```
private Employee GetEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    if (employee == null)
    {
        return new Employee()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "John",
        };
    }

    employee.ID = 1;
    employee.Name = "John";
    return employee;
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/11/how-are-parameters-passed-in-c-are-they-passed-by-reference-or-by-value/

Comment: Right, in that case the value IS the reference, you can't change the reference hence assigning something to the parameter does not do anything in the caller.

Comment: I'm not sure how it misconveys the passing of a reference. The REFERENCE is passed by value. I will edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Really not sure why Matias incorrect comment is upvoted, while my correct answer is downvoted.

Comment: @DavidL The original wording was 100% correct.  The reference *is* passed by value, which was exactly what was said.

Comment: @Servy, no it said that the reference is passed by value, "as is everything in C#", which seems misleading if the ref or out keyword is used.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer References *absolutely* are passed by value.  Everything not marked as `ref` or `out` is passed by value.  Creating a new reference to the same object *is creating a copy of that value* (that value being the reference).  That's what it means to pass something by value.

Comment: @DavidL Right, sorry, it should have said "by default" or "when not using ref/out" or some other such qualification.  The statement "the reference is passed by value" is completely correct, as that is the case here, the "as is everything" requires a qualification.

Comment: @Servy that was my only complaint with the original verbiage.  Now that it is been corrected I have no issues whatsoever with the current wording.

Comment: Right, I've dropped my comment. I don't know why I did that mistake. Sorry (BTW I didn't downvote your answer).

Comment: Uhm I believe a fast read of your answer made my brain think that we were talking about reference types vs. value types... which has nothing to do with your answer and even the Q&A itself. And then, I added an absolutely wrong comment :/ Oh and then, Servy The Punisher was summoned to point me my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`Employee` is a reference type, and what that means is that it's actually an address of the employee data.

the `employee` parameter in `GetEmployee` is just a copy of that address.  Since you know the address, you can change the information at the address, but since it is just a copy, any changes you make to the address itself, such as `employee = new Employee();` will not affect the address you passed in.

When you do `employee = new Employee();` you've overwritten the copied address with new address which points to a completely different employee in memory.  That's why you're not seeing any change in the Employee you've passed in.

Answer (score 0):

While you're passing a ***reference type*** to the whole method, a method argument will be a new reference to the same object **unless you use `ref` keyword**:

```
public class A {}

public class B
{
   public void DoStuff(A a) // <--- "a" is a new reference of type A
   {
        a = new A();
   }
}
```

So...

Calling `DoStuff` with the following code:

```
A a = null;
DoStuff(a);
```

...will give a null reference of type `A` to `DoStuff`. That is, you're not going to work with the reference given during method's call, but with **the argument**, thus, you won't update the source reference to point to the new object.

Otherwise, you would need to use `ref` keyword both in the method signature and when you call it somewhere:

```
public class B
{
   public void DoStuff(ref A a) // <--- "a" is a new reference of type A
   {
        // Now this will affect the reference that was passed
        // when this method is being called!
        a = new A();
   }
}

B b = new B();
A a = new A();
b.DoStuff(ref a);
```